# python package_data vs data_files vs extra_files

Tags: python, setuptools

python's setuptools offer three way to add *non-python* files to a package:

- package_data
- data_files
- extra_files

[This guide](https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/setupscript.html) has a quite geed description for `package_data` and `data_files`, but it doesn't mention the `extra_files`.

**What are the `extra_files` for? Or is it just a deprecated legacy option?**

Comment: There are no [`extra_files` in `distutils`](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=extra_files&unscoped_q=extra_files) nor [in `setuptools`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/search?q=extra_files&type=Code). Where have you found that `extra_files`?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/openstack/pbr/blob/master/pbr/tests/testpackage/setup.cfg). And I tried and it works

Comment: Oh, Yes it is from PBR. I missed it ...

Comment: It's [something](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/reference/api/pbr.html#module-pbr.extra_files) from [tag:python-pbr]. Extra addition for `setuptools`. I cannot find docs for it though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference:

`package_data` - defines files tightly related to the python package itself. eg. documentation, data files

`data_files` - defines files that don't fall into previous category eg. desktop icons, fonts, configuration files.

Example usage of the second one:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    data_files= [
        ("/usr/share/applications", ["my_package/my_application.desktop"]),
    ]
)
```

For directory - it's a target directory. You can use paths relative to `sys.prefix` or absolute path, but those with caution as it is incompatible with wheel packaging format.

For files, it's a source relative path from setup.py location.

Comment: please add more examples and hints/links